# Cannot find -lblas and -lgfortran when building UMFPACK

Tags: c++, fortran, cygwin, blas, umfpack

I'm trying to compile the UMFPACK for Windows using the Cygwin compiler following the steps provided in the following documentation: https://github.com/PetterS/SuiteSparse/tree/master/UMFPACK

However, when I run the `make` command after several minutes I get an error indicating

```
.../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lblas
.../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran
```

knowing that I edited the  `UMFPACK_CONFIG = -DNBLAS` in the `SuiteSparse_config/SuiteSparse_config.mk`.

I tried to search for similar problems on google but I couldn't find any working solution.

[image: screenshot of the error giving by cygwin after make of UMFPACK]

Comment: Can you compile a Fortran Hello world program?

Comment: it means your environment is missing certain libraries. I'm afraid I don't know enough about Cygwin, but this error under Linux usually means that (a) either the library isn't installed, or (b) the library wasn't found by the loader.

Comment: cygwin already has the umfpack library. Why do you need to build  your own ? https://sourceware.org/ml/cygwin-announce/2016-03/msg00073.html

Comment: @matzeri how can i use the builtin library in a c++ project i'm working on ? how can i include it in my project resources ?

Comment: Install the `libumfpack-devel` and `libumfpack1` packages. They includes the import libraries and the header of Umfpack.

Comment: @matzeri thank you, I used the cygwin to download the packages mentioned, but I have only one question, can I build the downloaded packages into a .dll file which i can use when releasing my application.